# How do I edit com.apple.locate.plist

Tags: plist

I just got a new iMac running Monterey.

I am running into issues with how to change files that I would normally think I could edit and modify if I'm logged in as `root` or `Administrator`.

One example is that I would like to change the frequency with which `locate`'s database is updated from once a week on Saturday to everyday.

I've tried to directly edit `/System/Library/LaunchDaemon/com.apple.locate.plist` but nothing I do seems to let me write on it.

These are thing things I've tried

- Signed in as Administrator `sudo pico /System/Library/LaunchDaemon/com.apple.locate.plist`

This  just gives me an Error message, *Error write .... Operation not permitted*

- I've gone in as `root` and tried to similarly edit the file with the same results.
- As `Administrator` or `root` I opened the `/System/Library/LaunchDaemon` in Finder, right clicked to *Get Info*.  There it says I can only read the file.  I've tried then editing the permissions, but I'm denied this.  I get the message *The operation can't be completed because you don't have the necessary permission*.  How is it possible that `Administrator` and `root` don't the necessary permissions?  How do I grant them permission to do these things?
- I've tried doing something like `sudo chown $USER ...` and `sudo chmod u+w ...` but these similarly fail.
- I also went into *Recovery Mode* and ran `csrutil disable`.  This had no effect on my ability to modify anything.

How is it that I actually edit things belonging like this?

Comment: Files in /System are protected by SIP. Why do you need to edit that file in the first place (there may be other ways to accomplish this)?

Comment: @nohillside I understand that they are protected by SIP.  That's why I ran `csrutil disable`.  But that had no effect.

Comment: @nohillside Why?  Because I want to?  Because `locate` is working a bit wonky and I don't want to have to wait a week each time I try to fix it to see whether it's properly updated itself.  Because this particular action is rather benign and should be easily accomplished but I'm being blocked.

Comment: I would just create a user-defined LaunchDaemon based on com.apple.locate.plist and have it run at all other days of the week. Seems easier than changing a system file after each update (and resealing the system volume with more recent versions of macOS).

Comment: @nohillside At this point, your suggestion exceeds my knowledge base.  Are you saying there is no way to gain access to these files to edit it?  That's really all I'd like to know how to do right now.

Comment: @nohillside My question is less about this particular `plist`.  It's just the occasion to be frustrated by makers of a computer deciding to make my life more difficult when I want/need to adjust something.  So, I just want an answer about how to edit such a file.  If I continue to have problems with locate, then I'll post questions on that later.

Comment: Starting with Big Sur, the System volume is sealed (https://eclecticlight.co/2020/11/30/is-big-surs-system-volume-sealed/), meaning all files are crypographically signed and the system will refuse to boot if they are tampered with/changed. There are ways to re-seal the volume after a change, but it's a rather cumbersome procedure and would need to be repeated after each minor update.

Comment: @nohillside OK.  That's not pleasant to hear.  So, then could you then explain to me how to create the user-defined LaunchDaemon you suggested?

Comment: There are a lot of questions about writing/installing LaunchDaemon plists on AD already, and a lot of material available in general (https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=write+launch+daemon+on+macos&ia=web). If you can't get it to work, please ask a new question and include the research you've done.

Comment: @nohillside Could you then at least point me at a good question to start with?  I've never create such a LaunchDaemon before.  I have no idea even what to ask or do other than:  how is it done?

Comment: Check the links returned by Duckduckgo, or use https://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/